# How do I remove checkmarks from "other rows" in a UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, nstableview

I have a UITableViewController and a list of checkboxes in each section.  What is the correct way to

- Fetch the rows for the section
- Change the checkbox of the section so that I correctly update my backing data view, and the UX view as well?

... in other words, I want only *one* checkmark within section 1.  I tried using NSIndexPath, however the properties are read only.

[image]

**Code**

```
    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Section ==1)
        {
            var thisCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

            if (thisCell.Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.None)
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
            else
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }

        if (indexPath.Section ==2)
        {
            var thisCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

            if (thisCell.Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.None)
            {
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;

                // Somehow deselect all the checkboxes in the other rows
               // I can't set NSIndexPath properties on a new object... so I'm stuck

            }
            else
            { 
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to create a NSIndexPath is located in a static method...

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Section ==1)
        {
            var thisCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

            if (thisCell.Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.None)
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
            else
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }

        if (indexPath.Section ==2)
        {
            var thisCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

            if (thisCell.Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.None)
            {
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;

                // Somehow deselect all the checkboxes in the other ro
                for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++)
                {
                    if (i == indexPath.Row)
                        continue;

                    var tmpRowIndex = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(i, indexPath.Section);
                    var otherCell = tableView.CellAt(tmpRowIndex);

                    if (otherCell == null)
                        break;
                    else 
                        otherCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                thisCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            }
        }
    }
```